# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gui.pyw'; 'gui' is not a package

Tags: python

My main script is in (local-directory)/desktop/code and I'm trying to import a Python script from the same folder by running:

```
import gui.pyw
```

The GUI loads when I execute the main script but the main script doesn't.

When I close the GUI, it gives me the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gui.pyw'; 'gui' is not a package
```

I don't know why it's not finding it. any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Confused. What do you mean "The GUI loads when I execute the main script but the main script doesn't."

Comment: @astrochun the main script should print out an output in the terminal but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe be you should just write `import gui`. When you are writing `import gui.pyw`, it is assuming `pyw` as a function in the `gui` script instead of importing/running the whole script.

Comment: Thanks! That worked but I feel stupid for not trying that now lol